# Gramps detailed ancestral report with web addresses?

Tags: gramps

Is it possible to generate a detailed ancestral report in Gramps that contains web addresses associated with each person in the report? [This is the report](https://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Gramps_5.0_Wiki_Manual_-_Reports_-_part_6#Detailed_Ancestral_Report) that can be reached by going to **Reports** > **Text** > **Detailed Ancestral Report...**

Looking at the **Options** and **Options 2** tab in the report dialog I see many options for including various things in the report. "Include Notes", "Include Sources", "Includes Source Notes", "Include Addresses". I thought "Include Addresses" might cause the generated report to include web addresses, but it does not. Is there a workaround to get the addresses present on the report?

Comment: What do you mean by "web addresses"? Are you talking about a specific field in Gramps? + which version of Gramps?

Comment: @wotter, sorry for the late reply. I'm interested in the fields present under the "Internet" tab in the person dialog. I've stored links to various web pages using UI under that tab. This is Gramps 5.0.1, but if I remember correctly it was the same in the version 4 of Gramps that I had.